# QPlainTextEdit dropEvent while setReadOnly(true)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've managed how to accept drop events on a `QPlainTextEdit` with:

```
class PlainTextEdit : public QPlainTextEdit {
public:
    PlainTextEdit() {
//        setReadOnly(true);
    }
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) {
        qDebug() << "drag";
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    }
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) {
        qDebug() << "drop";
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    }
};
```

But it seems to work only if `setReadOnly(false);`. Isn't possible to have both?

The code above works only when:

```
//        setReadOnly(true);
```

Uncomment and it prevents drop.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense logic-wise. A text control being read-only means that the user can not change it's contents. Drop event is one of the ways for the user to change the contents of the text control. So they kind of contradict each other.

Comment: You probably need to also override dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *) to force it to accept() the QDragEnterEvent object.  The built-in dragEnterEvent() method calls ignore() on the QDragEnterEvent object when the widget is in read-only state, for the reasons SingerOfTheFall mentioned.

Comment: You can use `installEventFilter` on instance of your `PlainTextEdit`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Override `dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *)` isn't enough here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to accept drop event even if `readOnly` is set to `true`, you can try to manually unset `readOnly`, accept an action and set `readOnly` back. Not really smooth solution but it works in the test project I've just made.

cpp:

```
void LineEdit::dropEvent(QDropEvent *e)
{
    e->acceptProposedAction();
    QPlainTextEdit::dropEvent(e);
    if (wasReadOnly)
        setReadOnly(true);
}

void LineEdit::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *e)
{
    wasReadOnly = isReadOnly();
    if (wasReadOnly)
        setReadOnly(false);
    e->acceptProposedAction();
}

void LineEdit::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *e)
{
    if (wasReadOnly)
        setReadOnly(true);
}
```

h:

```
private:
    bool wasReadOnly;
```

Be sure you change `readOnly` back after doing all drops.